# masm, линковка.asm у которого путь имеет пробелы и русские буквы

Tags: ассемблер, link, masm32

Помогите разобраться с линковкой, как сделать правильно команду чтобы не вылазила ошибка 
`LINK : fatal error LNK1181: cannot open input file "D:\═ютр  яряър\YandexDisk\asm\code.obj"`
при выполнении ...
`masm32\bin\link.exe /SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE "D:\═ютр  яряър\YandexDisk\asm\code.obj"`?

Мда, как то так :(
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если вы линкуетесь из .BAT-скрипта, попробуйте использовать [раскрытие параметров в короткое имя](https://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/percent.mspx?mfr=true): `%~s1`

Например:

```
rem link.bat
masm32\bin\link.exe /SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE %~s1
```

(если вы вызываете его как `link.bat "D:\Новая папка\YandexDisk\asm.code.obj"`)

---

Если вы вызываете компоновщик C#, попробуйте перевести имя файла в короткую версию самостоятельно. Это делается так:

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
static extern uint GetShortPathName(string path, StringBuilder shortPathBuf, uint bufSize);

public static string ToShortPathName(string longName)
{
    // запрашиваем желаемый размер буфера
    uint bufferSize = GetShortPathName(longName, null, 0);
    while (true)
    {
        var shortNameBuffer = new StringBuilder((int)bufferSize);
        // проверяем, подошёл ли буфер (избегаем race condition с внешним миром)
        uint result = GetShortPathName(longName, shortNameBuffer, bufferSize);
        // ошибка -> исключение
        if (result == 0)
            throw new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());
        // хватило места -- хорошо
        if (result <= bufferSize)
            return shortNameBuffer.ToString();
        // нет -- идём на следующий круг
        bufferSize = result;
    }
}
```

Comment: Не, а если я из под программы(C#) вызываю?
                startInfo2.FileName = "C:\\masm32\\bin\\link.exe";
                startInfo2.Arguments = "/SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE \"" + wintodos(Environment.CurrentDirectory) + "\\sourcecode.obj\"";

Comment: @Alex_Rudenkiy: Окей, обновил ответ.

Comment: А почему у меня ошибка, тему обновил (((

Comment: @Alex_Rudenkiy: Ну, в ошибке ж написано — такого файла не существует. Перепроверьте!

Comment: @Alex_Rudenkiy: Вы бы передавали правильное имя каталога: `Новая папка`. У вас так какая-то функция `wintodos`, думаю, она всё портит.

Comment: Спасибо, выручили :D

Comment: @Alex_Rudenkiy: Пожалуйста!